# Javascript Rest API fetch calls in for loop not setting value to elements

Tags: javascript, rest, api, asynchronous, wikipedia-api

I'm attempting to get image URLs from Wikipedia, if they exist, based on a list of terms. The API call works when I just call once, but once it's in a for loop, it doesn't set the result to the `img src=`. If I put in `alert()`'s and slow it down, it is definitely getting the URLs.

I made a CodePen to demonstrate: https://codepen.io/justiceorjustus/pen/aeOEvW

Ultimately, it's supposed to get the image URL and then set it to the image source based on the id.

Javascript:

```
var wikiImageURLs = ["blueweed",
"buttercup_annual",
"horseweed_(marestail)",
"lambsquarters_common",
"ragweed_common",
"spurge_thyme-leaf",
"bedstraw_annual",
"bluebur",
"burdock",
"clover_white_sweet",
"clover_bur",
"cocklebur",
"croton_wooly",
"dogbane_hemp",
"ironweed_tall",
"lettuce_wild",
"mustard_tanzy",
"radish_wild",
"ragwort_tanzy",
"shepherds_purse",
"amaranth_spiny",
"buttercup_tall",
"chickweed_mouseear",
"clover_white",
"Dandelion",
"dock_curly",
"galinsoga_hairy",
"goatsbeard",
"henbit",
"ironweed_western",
"ivy_ground",
"kochia",
"lespedeze",
"oxalis",
"pennycress_field",
"pepperweed_field",
"pigweed_redroot",
"plantain_broadleaf",
"plantain_narrow-leaf",
"purslane_annual",
"sneezeweed_bitter",
"sowthistle_annual",
"sunflower",
"thistle_Russian",
"vetch",
"violet_wild",
"wormwood_biennial",
"yellow_rocket",
"bindweed_field",
"carrot_wild",
"chicory",
"cinquefoil",
"dogfennel",
"fleabane_annual",
"goldenrod",
"horsenettle",
"kudzu",
"marshelder",
"milkweed",
"pepperweed_perennial",
"pokeweed",
"sesbania_hemp",
"sowthistle_perennial",
"spurge_leafy",
"thistle_bull",
"thistle_Canada",
"thistle_musk_(nodding)",
    "yarrow"];

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < wikiImageURLs.length; i++)
        {
             fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/' + wikiImageURLs[i])
                 .then(response => {
                    if(response.ok) return response.json();
                    throw new Error(response.statusText);
                 })
                 .then(function handleData(data) {
                     var wikiImageURL = data.thumbnail.source.replace("320px", "262px");
                     //alert(wikiImageURL);
                    document.getElementById(wikiImageURLs[i]).src = wikiImageURL;
                 })
                 .catch(function handleError(error) {

            });
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
            <img id="blueweed" /> blueweed
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="buttercup_annual" /> buttercup, annual
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="horseweed_(marestail)" /> horseweed, (marestail)
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="lambsquarters_common" /> lambsquarters, common
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="ragweed_common" /> ragweed, common
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="spurge_thyme-leaf" /> spurge, thyme-leaf
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="bedstraw_annual" /> bedstraw, annual
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="bluebur" /> bluebur
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="burdock" /> burdock
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="clover_white_sweet" /> clover, white sweet
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="clover_bur" /> clover, bur
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="cocklebur" /> cocklebur
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="croton_wooly" /> croton, wooly
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="dogbane_hemp" /> dogbane, hemp
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="ironweed_tall" /> ironweed, tall
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="lettuce_wild" /> lettuce, wild
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="mustard_tanzy" /> mustard, tanzy
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="radish_wild" /> radish, wild
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="ragwort_tanzy" /> ragwort, tanzy
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="shepherd&#39;s_purse" /> shepherd&#39;s purse
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="amaranth_spiny" /> amaranth, spiny
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="buttercup_tall" /> buttercup, tall
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="chickweed_mouseear" /> chickweed, mouseear
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="clover_white" /> clover, white
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="Dandelion" /> Dandelion
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="dock_curly" /> dock, curly
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="galinsoga_hairy" /> galinsoga, hairy
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="goatsbeard" /> goatsbeard
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="henbit" /> henbit
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="ironweed_western" /> ironweed, western
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="ivy_ground" /> ivy, ground
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="kochia" /> kochia
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="lespedeze" /> lespedeze
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="oxalis" /> oxalis
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="pennycress_field" /> pennycress, field
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="pepperweed_field" /> pepperweed, field
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="pigweed_redroot" /> pigweed, redroot
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="plantain_broadleaf" /> plantain, broadleaf
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="plantain_narrow-leaf" /> plantain, narrow-leaf
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="purslane_annual" /> purslane, annual
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="sneezeweed_bitter" /> sneezeweed, bitter
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="sowthistle_annual" /> sowthistle, annual
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="sunflower" /> sunflower
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="thistle_Russian" /> thistle, Russian
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="vetch" /> vetch
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="violet_wild" /> violet, wild
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="wormwood_biennial" /> wormwood, biennial
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="yellow_rocket" /> yellow rocket
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="bindweed_field" /> bindweed, field
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="carrot_wild" /> carrot, wild
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="chicory" /> chicory
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="cinquefoil" /> cinquefoil
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="dogfennel" /> dogfennel
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="fleabane_annual" /> fleabane, annual
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="goldenrod" /> goldenrod
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="horsenettle" /> horsenettle
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="kudzu" /> kudzu
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="marshelder" /> marshelder
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="milkweed" /> milkweed
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="pepperweed_perennial" /> pepperweed, perennial
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="pokeweed" /> pokeweed
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="sesbania_hemp" /> sesbania, hemp
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="sowthistle_perennial" /> sowthistle, perennial
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="spurge_leafy" /> spurge, leafy
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="thistle_bull" /> thistle, bull
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="thistle_Canada" /> thistle, Canada
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="thistle_musk_(nodding)" /> thistle, musk (nodding)
        </div>
        <div>
            <img id="yarrow" /> yarrow
        </div>
```

I'm not really good with async requests, so I think the problem might be something dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I recommend using recursion as a repeat loop, because like this, the next query will only happen when the previous one has finished and so your browser will not hang.
Example:

```
    var wikiImageURLs = [
      "blueweed",
      "buttercup_annual",
      "horseweed_(marestail)",
      "lambsquarters",
      "ragweed",
      "spurge_thyme-leaf",
      "bedstraw_annual",
      "bluebur",
      "burdock",
      "clover_white_sweet",
      "clover_bur",
      "cocklebur",
      "croton_wooly",
      "dogbane_hemp",
      "ironweed_tall",
      "lettuce_wild",
      "mustard_tanzy",
      "radish_wild",
      "ragwort_tanzy",
      "shepherds_purse",
      "amaranth_spiny",
      "buttercup_tall",
      "chickweed_mouseear",
      "clover_white",
      "Dandelion",
      "dock_curly",
      "galinsoga_hairy",
      "goatsbeard",
      "henbit",
      "ironweed_western",
      "ivy_ground",
      "kochia",
      "lespedeze",
      "oxalis",
      "pennycress_field",
      "pepperweed_field",
      "pigweed_redroot",
      "plantain_broadleaf",
      "plantain_narrow-leaf",
      "purslane_annual",
      "sneezeweed_bitter",
      "sowthistle_annual",
      "sunflower",
      "thistle_Russian",
      "vetch",
      "violet_wild",
      "wormwood_biennial",
      "yellow_rocket",
      "bindweed_field",
      "carrot_wild",
      "chicory",
      "cinquefoil",
      "dogfennel",
      "fleabane_annual",
      "goldenrod",
      "horsenettle",
      "kudzu",
      "marshelder",
      "milkweed",
      "pepperweed_perennial",
      "pokeweed",
      "sesbania_hemp",
      "sowthistle_perennial",
      "spurge_leafy",
      "thistle_bull",
      "thistle_Canada",
      "thistle_musk_(nodding)",
      "yarrow"
    ];

    function fetchWikipedia(counter) {
      if (counter < wikiImageURLs.length) {
        fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/' + wikiImageURLs[counter])
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok)
                  return response.json();
                  throw new Error(response.statusText);
            })
            .then(function handleData(data) {
                if (data.thumbnail) { //I added this line, cause sometimes the query doesn't come with the thumbnail attribute 
                  var wikiImageURL = data.thumbnail.source.replace("320px", "262px");
                  document.getElementById(wikiImageURLs[counter]).src = wikiImageURL;
                }
                fetchWikipedia(counter + 1);
            })
            .catch(function handleError(error) {
                fetchWikipedia(counter + 1);
            });
       }
    }

    $(function () {
      $(document).ready(function () {
        fetchWikipedia(0);//value initial of counter
      });
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly what I didn't understand how to do.  I got to the point where I was pulling only one random image at a time... I didn't know how to wait until one request was done before getting another.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem, @justiceorjustus =)

Answer (score 0):

There is no image URL in the response for that route, also you have some ids in the array which not exists in the template, and you have unnecessary chained promise. Code below works but I hardcoded a random image URL. Once you found a new API route which returns the image URL, you can simply edit this code.

```
var wikiImageURLs = ["blueweed"];

        for (let i = 0; i < wikiImageURLs.length; i++)
        {
             console.log(wikiImageURLs[i])
             fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/' + wikiImageURLs[i]).then(response =>          {
                 console.log(response)
                 document.getElementById(wikiImageURLs[i]).src = 'https://i.imgur.com/4rj27vq.jpg?1';
             }).catch(err=>console.log(err));
        }
```